# Check Request Headers using XACML in Fiware platform

Tags: fiware, xacml3, authzforce, fiware-wilma, fiware-keyrock

I'm trying to integrate AuthzForce with Keyrock for advanced PDP and wanted to know how custom headers check rule can be made in XACML policies. As per my understanding and documentation, they've specified that with AuthzForce its possible to check the body, match time of request and more. But nowhere i could find a resource on how a policy/rule can be made to check custom headers.
Any suggestion or link for any documentation is appreciated.

Comment: You have to configure your PEP to send the request headers you want to the PDP and which XACML attributes (identifiers, datatypes) to use for those header values. In Fiware ecosystem, this is done with the PEP called Wilma. Are you using Wilma?
https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.PEP-Proxy

Comment: @cdan Thanks for your reply. Yes I am using wilma and Jason's comment helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cdan is correct - the Authzforce PDP, like any PDP can only adjudicate on matters if it is passed the appropriate information. The PEP Proxy you use will need to obtain and forward the information needed to adjudicate. For example, in the Wilma PEP Proxy, the payload for Authzforce is defined [here](https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy/blob/master/lib/pdp/authzforce.js)

In the Wilma PEP Proxy the the XACML Policy is defined in JavaScript as shown below and then translated into XML before being sent to Authzforce:

```js
const XACMLPolicy = {
    Request: {
      xmlns: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17',
      CombinedDecision: 'false',
      ReturnPolicyIdList: 'false',
      Attributes: [
        {
          Category: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject',
          Attribute: [
            {
                "AttributeId":"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id",
                "IncludeInResult": "false",
                "AttributeValue":{
                    "DataType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string",
                    "$t":"joe"
                }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          Category: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource',
          Attribute: [
            {
              AttributeId: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id',
              IncludeInResult: 'false',
              AttributeValue: {
                DataType: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string',
                $t: appId
              }
            },
            {
              AttributeId: 'urn:thales:xacml:2.0:resource:sub-resource-id',
              IncludeInResult: 'false',
              AttributeValue: {
                DataType: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string',
                $t: escapeXML(resource)
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          Category: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action',
          Attribute: {
            AttributeId: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id',
            IncludeInResult: 'false',
            AttributeValue: {
              DataType: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string',
              $t: action
            }
          }
        },
        {
          Category: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment'
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

Each Attribute in this payload is something that may need to be checked.
To add a check for a custom header, you'll need to extract it from the incoming payload and add another attribute (of category `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource`) with an appropriate `AttributeId`.

Of course the XACML rules you define will also need to refer to this same new Attribute Id when setting the access policy e.g. *"if custom header present then **PERMIT** else **DENY**"*.

Comment: Thank You very much for your help. It took me quite some time to understand but your comments helped and solved what I wanted.